# How do you validate fstab without rebooting?

Tags: fedora, mount, fstab

I modified `/etc/fstab`.

I verified the new devices and I can mount them with the `mount` command.

How may I validate the modifications made to `/etc/fstab` ?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You can simple run: `mount -a`

> -a
> Mount all filesystems (of the given types) mentioned in fstab.

This command will mount all (not-yet-mounted) filesystems mentioned in fstab and is used in system script startup during booting.

Comment: ...and compare it to /etc/mtab once you've done a "sudo mount -a", just to make sure all your options have been honoured.

Comment: `mount -a` by rereading `/etc/fstab` would also reload `/etc/mtab` so he should be fine with that only.

Comment: isn't that the point which adebaumann is trying to raise here? mount -a might return success, but doesn't necessarily mean that all the specific mount options have been honoured. since this will also reload /etc/mtab, you should check to see if all option are working?

Comment: You may need to run a "systemctl daemon-reload" before this. Mount uses systemd's view of the world and if that is not updated you will just be loading what was present at last boot

Answer (score 111):

The mount command take an `--fake` or `-f` for short. The following command should do what you need:

```
mount -fav
```

The following is in the documentation for `-f` option:

> Causes everything to be done except for the actual system call; if it's not obvious, this  ``fakes''  mounting  the filesystem.  This option is useful in conjunction with the -v flag to determine what the mount command is trying to do.

(Note this is Linux - check before using elsewhere: FreeBSD uses `-f` for 'force' - exactly the opposite meaning.)

Comment: mount -fav doesn't check that device with specified UUID is actually in the system. Also one would like to combine -f with -n not to pollute /etc/mtab

Comment: I like `mount --fake -a` but it seems to return `exit code($?)=0` always. Umm..

Comment: Also the fake option does not check whether the directory exists. It says `successfully mounted` even when the mount point dosent exist

Comment: This seems to be a good first thing to try, but you should also do a "mount -a" afterwards to verify.  In my case, I set the options to "default" instead of "defaults" (which was preventing my Pi from booting), but `mount -fav` validated it as correct.  As soon as I did a `mount -a` it found an error.

Comment: work with me `"Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"`

Comment: @AlexandrPriymak it seems like `mount -fav` checks whether the specified UUID is on the system (running CentOS 7).  Probably back in 2015, it didn't.

Answer (score 111):

`sudo findmnt --verify --verbose` is the best way I've found

Comment: Amazing answer.  I'd never heart of findmnt before, but it's really fully-featured and part of util-linux!

Comment: `findmnt` told me that `fuse.sshfs seems unsupported by the current kernel`, which is not true because I was able to mount the sshfs share with `mount -a`

Comment: this could not detect typos XD `errors=remout-ro` for example, i have to boot using another live cd to investigate

Answer (score 9):

Note that if you add a swap file to your fstab, `mount -a` won't turn it on: you'll want to run `swapon -a`.

Answer (score 4):

I found this /problem/ but the solution didn't meet my requirements.

When rebooting with any invalid entries in the /etc/fstab, such as missing file systems that fsck cannot check; the system will fail to boot.  That can be much more difficult to deal with if you have a headless box.

This is my solution to checking /etc/fstab to avoid this boot problem:

```
    # cat /usr/local/bin/check-fstab-uuid-entries.sh
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    for x in $(grep ^UUID /etc/fstab|cut -d \  -f 1|cut -d = -f 2)
    do
            if [ ! -h /dev/disk/by-uuid/$x ];then
                    echo $(grep $x /etc/fstab)  ..... not found
            fi
    done
```

Comment: Nice script, but can you please explain what it does?

Comment: @PeterWippermann Well, it just checks fstab entries using UUID to make sure the volume is available; if it wasn't available then boot would stop and require intervention to continue.  I think other options might be better, like `mount -fav` ...

Answer (score 3):

TBH even fake mounting doesn't safely validate the fstab for bad fs type entries.

you can have entries that have correct uuid's, directories etc but if you specify a noexistant FS type this will halt your boot next time.

```
[root@grumpy ~]# grep backup /etc/fstab
UUID=5ed48e5e-7251-4d49-a273-195cf0432a89       /mnt/backup     noatime,nodiratime,xfs defaults,nodev,nosuid    0 0
[root@grump ~]#

[root@grumpy ~]# mount -fav | grep backup
/mnt/backup              : successfully mounted
[root@grumpy ~]#
```

Answer (score 2):

**mount -a** is safe method to check /etc/fstab otherwise wrong entry could break the system

It is also advised to keep a backup copy of original /etc/fstab file. it could be copied to home directory of root

Answer (score 2):

I open another term or tab and run:  tail -f /var/log/kern.log

Sometimes errors show there that don't show when mounting.