# How to force s3fs mount on boot

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I'm using [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) 1.33 on Ubuntu 9.10 x86.

I mount it manually with this command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/s3fs mybucket /mnt/s3/mybucket -ouse_cache=/tmp
```

How can I force the mount on boot?

I guess that I have to write something to `/etc/fstab`. But what? And how do I test it without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the [Ubuntu RcLocalHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto) to create `/etc/init.d/local`, and then put your command in that file.  The mount will then happen automatically on boot.

To test, invoke `/etc/init.d/local` manually on the command line (as root).  You should see that causes the mount to occur.

EDIT: doing the mount from /etc/fstab should work fine too, according to the [s3fs faq](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon):

> s3fs#example.com /mnt/s3/blah fuse _netdev,use_cache=/tmp,use_rrs=1,allow_other  0 0

Reason to prefer the /etc/init.d/local approach: it's simpler to set up, just put your existing mount script in that file.

Reason to prefer the fstab approach: it's a more standard way to do mounts, and someone who doesn't know about your setup can just look in /etc/fstab to determine what mounts your machine is making.

Comment: Is this the best way? Why not the fstab?

Comment: Is that fstab line, it should be `_netdev`, otherwise mount will throw an error.

Comment: and how to test without rebooting -- `mount -a` will mount everything in fstab. Answered [here](http://serverfault.com/a/174182) with more detail.